# Pivot Table Chart Macro

Tags: excel, pivot, vba

I have a sheet with multiple pivot tables of changing sizes that I need put into a chart. I need a macro that will find each pivot table and create the chart for them. Here is what I have so far. What it is doing is only creating a chart based on the first pivot tables data. The references a number that changes from 1 to 2 to 3 etc. as it goes from different table to table

```
Sub CreateChart(i, v, SheetName)
Dim objPivot As PivotTable, objPivotRange As Range, objChart As chart

If ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
Set objPivot = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(i)

Set objChart = Charts.Add

Set objPivotRange = objPivot.TableRange1

 With objChart
.SetSourceData objPivotRange
.ChartType = xl3DColumn
.Legend.Delete
.ApplyDataLabels
.Location xlLocationAsNewSheet, SheetName & " Chart"
End With

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotChartActiveFields = False

End Sub
```

So F'ing stackoverflow wont let me respond to any comments left to answer this question which is bull$hit. but anyways, the tables are all named uniquely as pivottable1 pivottable2, etc. Therefore it makes no difference whether I index or use pivottablename.

Comment: Are you passing in unique index values (i)?

Answer (score 0):

Name the tables and pass the table name instead of index number.

```
Set chartTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(ptTableN)
```